# Different result when using subquery and join : SQL-1454. Active Users

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

```
Input: 
Accounts table:
+----+----------+
| id | name     |
+----+----------+
| 1  | Winston  |
| 7  | Jonathan |
+----+----------+
Logins table:
+----+------------+
| id | login_date |
+----+------------+
| 7  | 2020-05-30 |
| 1  | 2020-05-30 |
| 7  | 2020-05-31 |
| 7  | 2020-06-01 |
| 7  | 2020-06-02 |
| 7  | 2020-06-02 |
| 7  | 2020-06-03 |
| 1  | 2020-06-07 |
| 7  | 2020-06-10 |
+----+------------+
Output: 
+----+----------+
| id | name     |
+----+----------+
| 7  | Jonathan |
+----+----------+
```

Explanation:
User Winston with id = 1 logged in 2 times only in 2 different days, so, Winston is not an active user.
User Jonathan with id = 7 logged in 7 times in 6 different days, five of them were consecutive days, so, Jonathan is an active user.

Active users are those who logged in to their accounts for five or more consecutive days.

Write an SQL query to find the id and the name of active users.

Return the result table ordered by id

I have encountered some problems with my codes doing this question.

My codes:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, a.name
FROM Accounts a
LEFT JOIN Logins l
ON a.id = l.id
JOIN Logins l1
ON l.id=l1.id AND DATEDIFF(l.login_date, l1.login_date) BETWEEN 1 AND 4
GROUP BY l.login_date
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT l1.login_date) = 4
```

Input

```
{"headers":{"Accounts":["id","name"],"Logins":["id","login_date"]},"rows":{"Accounts":[[182,"Gavriel"],[119,"Naftali"],[31,"Yaakov"],[136,"Menachem"],[142,"Sarah"],[204,"Daniel"],[49,"Ezra"],[27,"David"]],"Logins":[[142,"2020-6-27"],[119,"2020-6-29"],[31,"2020-6-26"],[27,"2020-6-27"],[182,"2020-7-2"],[136,"2020-6-28"],[142,"2020-7-5"],[27,"2020-6-29"],[136,"2020-6-27"],[49,"2020-7-1"],[204,"2020-7-1"],[49,"2020-7-5"],[204,"2020-7-3"],[49,"2020-7-3"],[31,"2020-7-3"],[204,"2020-7-3"],[142,"2020-6-30"],[119,"2020-6-26"],[142,"2020-6-29"],[136,"2020-7-2"],[49,"2020-7-2"],[182,"2020-7-4"],[119,"2020-6-29"],[49,"2020-6-30"],[136,"2020-7-5"],[27,"2020-7-2"],[136,"2020-6-28"],[31,"2020-6-29"],[204,"2020-7-3"],[142,"2020-6-29"],[31,"2020-6-30"],[204,"2020-6-27"],[204,"2020-7-2"],[182,"2020-6-27"],[31,"2020-7-3"],[119,"2020-7-4"],[142,"2020-6-27"],[119,"2020-6-27"],[27,"2020-6-26"],[142,"2020-7-2"],[27,"2020-6-28"],[136,"2020-6-26"],[119,"2020-6-27"],[142,"2020-7-1"],[27,"2020-7-1"],[31,"2020-6-29"],[204,"2020-6-28"],[136,"2020-6-28"],[204,"2020-7-3"],[31,"2020-6-28"],[182,"2020-6-29"],[49,"2020-7-4"],[204,"2020-6-27"],[136,"2020-7-5"],[142,"2020-7-4"],[31,"2020-7-2"],[182,"2020-7-1"],[204,"2020-6-28"],[31,"2020-7-4"],[136,"2020-7-1"],[136,"2020-6-26"],[27,"2020-7-4"],[27,"2020-6-29"],[31,"2020-7-2"]]}}
```

My Output:

```
{"headers": ["id", "name"], "values": [[49, "Ezra"], [136, "Menachem"], [142, "Sarah"], [182, "Gavriel"]]}
```

Expected Output:

```
{"headers":["id","name"],"values":[[49,"Ezra"]]}
```

Correct Answer:

```
SELECT DISTINCT l1.id,
(SELECT name FROM Accounts WHERE id = l1.id) AS name
FROM Logins l1
JOIN Logins l2 ON l1.id = l2.id AND DATEDIFF(l2.login_date, l1.login_date) BETWEEN 1 AND 4
GROUP BY l1.id, l1.login_date
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT l2.login_date) = 4
```

In my answer, I join the Accounts table instead of use subquery as in answer. However, I don't understand why my code will lead to such an different output.

Comment: Notice you did not grouped by the id as well...

Answer (score 1):

Please try this query:

```
with data as (
select 
id,l_date,
--lag(l_date) over(partition by id order by l_date) lag_date,
l_date - lag(l_date) over(partition by id order by l_date),
case when l_date - lag(l_date) over(partition by id order by l_date) > 1 then 1 else 0 end as session_change

from login
),
staging_data as (
select 
id,l_date,sum(session_change)
over(partition by id order by l_date rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as session
from data )
select id
from staging_data
group by id,session having count(*) >=5
```